# Saving a huge 10GB file with vim

Tags: mysql, windows, vim

I need to edit and save a huge 10GB text file using the vim GUI. I am new to vim and using the GUI. I was able to load the file, make the appropriate changes, however, when I click on the save icon (also tried save all files icon), vim seems to save a small 3MB version of the file with the remainder of it missing.

How am I supposed to save this huge file using vim, after I perform the edits?

Comment: Are the edits something you could do with `sed`?

Comment: Or, are they localised such that you could use `dd` to extract a few MB to edit and then rebuild your file afterwards?

Comment: No, I am using the vim GUI, I am running windows.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Most (if not all) of core- and binutils are available on windows (search for gnuwin32 project), more are available on windows with cygwin. AFAIK vim loads the whole file into memory and, when saving, writes the whole file, thus trying to edit 10 GB file with vim is usually not a good idea. If you can reproduce the issue with some easily compressable file it would be good to go with it to vim-dev: there are developers that know memfile.c/memline.c: they contain structures and functions that Vim uses to operate on file.

Comment: Compressable file is required so that you can send it via email. “Compression” may as well be a script that generates this file.

Answer (score 1):

as a first step, you should install [LargeFile](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LargeFile) plugin, that sets a number of setting to the the value that makes more sense when editing large files. Then you will have a much better chance of this working for you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is more suitable as comment however, as this is not a tested solution.